# Activating masonry after jQuery .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry

How do i activate JS and other jquery functions, like masonry after the page is loaded.

i use:

```
jQuery("#filterbox").load("mypage.html"}); works fine, but eg. mansory is not activated.
jQuery('#content #boxes').masonry({ columnWidth: 122, animate: true });
```

but the second is not "activated".

is it correct that css, and js is not activated during .load, and if, how do i activate it afterward.

Thanks for any help..

/regards

Comment: http://desandro.com/demo/masonry/docs/ Masonry arranges elements vertically then horizontally according to a grid.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
jQuery("#filterbox").load("mypage.html", function(){
   $('#content #boxes').masonry({ columnWidth: 122, animate: true });
});
```

By the way, you have an extra `}` after `mypage.html`.

Answer (score 3):

Since jQuery.load is asynchronous, `jQuery('#content #boxes').masonry` will run DIRECTLY after the call to jQuery.load. You need a way to tell jQuery that you want to execute that function after the content actually has been loaded.

jQuery.load takes a callback function as the second argument. This callback will execute after your content has loaded. Try this:

```
jQuery("#filterbox").load("mypage.html", function() {
    jQuery('#content #boxes').masonry({ columnWidth: 122, animate: true });
});
```

Go ahead and read the [documentation for .load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you so much. i have struggled with this for days.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
jQuery("#filterbox").load("mypage.html",function() {
      jQuery('#content #boxes').masonry({ columnWidth: 122, animate: true });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a ImagesLoaded script 
https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded/blob/master/imagesloaded.js

Try:

```
jQuery("#filterbox").load("mypage.html",function() {
    jQuery('#content').imagesLoaded(function() {
        jQuery(this).masonry({ itemSelector: '.box' });
    });
});
```

It works for me, hope this helps you too

my example (choose gallery in navigation):
http://test.crystalstudio.me/nms/

Comment: `.box` - change this to Your selector